# Database table design to handle ordering items when there is inheritance of items

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've got a the following requirements for a database. It needs to be able to 
store items. Items have an id, identifier and title. Each item can have zero 
or more widgets and zero or more dodads. Each widget and each dodad has a
title, and a type. Dodads also have a default value. Also the order of the
widgets and dodas need to be saved.

I've got the following tables to do this:

```
items  widgets  dodads
-----  -------  ------
id     id       id
ident  itemId   itemId
title  title    title
       type     type
       order    order
                default
```

So now I would like to be able to have inheritence. Thats easy enough, add a
parentId to the items table. The problem is now the order columns in the widget
and the dodad tables.

Ordering for inheritance should works that the parent's items must be in tha
same order as the parent, but the child's items can be interwhoven. That is
something like the following should be doable:

```
P1
P2
C1
C2
P3
P4
C3
```

So the question is how can I store the overall order of widgets and dodads? I
assume I need another table but not sure the best way to go about it. It would be
nice if the table structure could deal with multipule parents.

Comment: Introduce a `Level` {0, 1, 3, ...} -- how far is the node away from the root; for the nodes on the same level something like {1.1, 1.2 ..}. BTW adding a `ParentID` to create tree is a "naive way"; search SO for `nested sets, closure table, path enumeration, levelled hierarchy..`

Answer (score 1):

Order isn't a database concept, it's a presentation concept (like how the data is presented in a screen or report).  It sounds like you're designing a storage structure based on one specific way which the data will be displayed to a user, which is usually a sign that something's off on your data design.  I can't really tell what exactly you're looking for because your P1/P2/C1/C2 example doesn't show any of the widgets or doodads, but I think that's the level you're having a problem with.

Semi-related: if the only difference between widgets and doodads is the 'default' column, why not put them in the same table with another type or category column?  That will help if part of the problem is sorting widgets and doodads in the same list.

Comment: Order is a display issue, but that order needs to be stored. There are more differences between a widget and a dodad, but I've just made a minor difference for a simple example. the P/C list is ment more that Parent or Child widget or dodad have their own ordering but can be intermingled. Its that intermingled order than I'm not sure how to save.